# Running two instances of ion-google-place in the same form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, google-places

I am trying to run two instances of ion-google place in the same form.  The use case is From address to To address.  However, even if I select something for From, it returns value to To.  Below is the example of my implementation.

```
$scope.toaddress = {
      location: ''
    };

$scope.$watch('toadrress.location', function(mynewVal, myoldVal) {
        if (mynewVal.hasOwnProperty('formatted_address')) {        
        var toaddressname = $scope.toadrress.location.name;
     }       
    });

$scope.fromddress = {
      location: ''
    };

$scope.$watch('fromadrress.location', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal.hasOwnProperty('formatted_address')) {        
        var fromaddressname = $scope.fromadrress.location.name;
     }       
    });
```